# How to record native iOS app requests in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have tried recording native iOS app ( developed in Swift and Objective C++ ) in Jmeter using proxy but it didn't worked .

I also tried recording native app ( removing SSL from app ) but it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 2):

For recording [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic you need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your mobile device. The file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and you need to pass it somehow to your iOS device (send by email, upload to a web server and open it in your browser, etc.)

The file is being generated under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Additionally you will need to switch on ["ENABLE FULL TRUST FOR ROOT CERTIFICATES"](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477), the setting lives under `Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings`

[image]

Be informed that the certificate has limited life span (7 days by default) so if you imported it a while ago you will need to reinstall the "fresh" version.

Also make sure to turn off the cellular data and [configure Wi-Fi adapter to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.howtogeek.com/293676/how-to-configure-a-proxy-server-on-an-iphone-or-ipad/), given you start the proxy and properly configure your device to use it you should be able to capture HTTP traffic without any extra setup and HTTPS traffic if you have the JMeter's certificate installed.

All the traffic which is not HTTP or HTTPS will not be captured/recorded

More information: [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri, I did all of the steps  many times but the thing is when the proxy is on the application doesn't work and the API's are not recorded. I also tried to record the application after removing SSL from the application but it didn't worked either. Does the device has to be Jailbreaked device ??